# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $X+Y\stackrel{d}{=}X$, then show that $\mathbb P(Y=0)=1$

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, characteristic-function

> Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $X+Y\stackrel{d}{=}X$, then show that $\mathbb P(Y=0)=1$. Can the independence condition be dropped?

I could solve the first part using characteristic functions, but I am stuck on the second part where I need to give a counterexample. I think we need to use symmetric random variables, but I can't construct anything concrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you drop the independence condition, consider the following.

$X$ takes $0$ and $1$ with equal probability.

$Y$ takes $\pm1$ with equal probability.

$X=0$ iff $Y=1$.

$X=1$ iff $Y=-1$.

Then $X+Y$ takes $0$ and $1$ with equal probability, which is exactly the distribution of $X$.

Comment: As a challenge, can you do it for continuous $Y?$

Comment: Quite general solution, extends Ben's answer below - If $F$ is the density function of $X$, then let $Y = -X + F^{-1}(1-F(X))$. So basically if $X=x$ is the 80th quantile of its density, $X+Y$ maps it to the 20th quantile and *vice versa*.

Comment: In this case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent...

Comment: @Xi'an That’s the point. If you allow for dependence, then $X+Y\overset{d}{=}X$ need not imply that $\mathbb P(Y=0)=1$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1)!

Answer (score 2):

One counterexample: Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$, $Z$ is a discrete random variable that is independent of $X$ and satisfy $P[Z = 0] = P[Z = -2] = 1/2$.  Define $Y = ZX$.

Then $X + Y = (1 + Z)X \sim N(0, 1)$ (why?).  Hence $X + Y \overset{d}{=} X$.  But clearly $P[Y = 0] < 1$: in fact, $P[Y = 0] = P[[Z = 0] \cup [X = 0]] \leq P[Z = 0] + P[X = 0] = 1/2$.

---

For the first part, here is a hint of an easier proof that does not call for characteristic function: compute $E[X + Y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X + Y)$ respectively.

Comment: In this case X and Y are not independent...

Comment: @Xi'an That's the point, right? -- an example such that $X + Y \overset{d}{=} X$ but $P[Y = 0] < 1$ if $X, Y$ are not independent, which shows that the "independence assumption" cannot be dropped.

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1)!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X$ has any symmetric distribution with mean $\mu$.  Taking $Y \equiv 2(\mu-X)$ (which is obviously not independent of $X$ unless the latter is a constant) then gives:

$$X + Y = X + 2(\mu-X) = 2\mu-X= \mu-(X-\mu) \overset{d}{=} X.$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1)!